# windows 10 does not have the option to allow enabling or disabling the device to wake the device

Tags: windows-10, power-management, device-manager

I want to prevent my machine to wake by the movement of my mouse, but after searching similar questions and issues, I am still not able to solve it. After opening the properties of my mouse, I expected to see the tab named 'power management' so that I check the box related enabling/disabling the device to wake the machine. My windows does not have this tab at all. It can be seen from the picture. [my mouse properties screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9IO.jpg)

Also, by running this script '-devicequery wake_armed' in cmd, I was going to see the devices that can wake my machine/ It clearly says NONE, but my mouse and keyboard can easily do it.

My device is surfacebook 2 if that helps.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Did you run the command `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` and did it return None?

Comment: If the mouse is external to the Surface Book (that is not built in), then you probably need to turn it off before suspending the Surface.

Comment: @harrymc yeah it returned None

Comment: What kind of a mouse?

Comment: This is done in Device Manager.

Comment: @harrymc It's a microsoft mouse. It should not be related to my mouse since I tried it on another device with windows 10 and power management tab was active on the other windows machine

Comment: I suggest to use Device Management, find your mouse (usually under "Human Interface Devices"), right-click it and do "Uninstall device", delete the driver if asked about it, then reboot. This will reinstall the mouse driver.